# Get array as result of ScriptEngine.eval()

Tags: javascript, java, arrays

I'm trying to use javax.script.ScriptEngine to `eval()` some JS scripts.
How can I know if the result after `eval()` which is of type `Object` is an array? And if so, how can I cast it?

Right now, to know if the object is of type Number or of type String i use `instanceof`. And when the result of the script is an array, if I print with `System.out.println()` the object returned it simply prints `[object Array]`.

Answer (score 2):

As you noticed, it's not java array but a javascript array, if you print the class of the return object, you probably will find it's "ScriptObjectMirror". I have a work around for this which is toString the array in another your script variable, then get the value of that (see below example). I believe there is a better way to resolve this array issue, waiting the good answer too.

```
engine.eval("var fruits = [\"Banana\", \"Orange\", \"Apple\", \"Mango\"]; var d = fruits.toString();");
System.out.println(engine.get("fruits").getClass());
System.out.println(engine.get("d").getClass());
System.out.println(engine.get("d"));
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case modifying the script to make it return list does the trick:

```
private String arrayToList() {
    if (javascript.startsWith("[") && javascript.endsWith("]"))
        javascript = "java.util.Arrays.asList(" + javascript + ")";
    return javascript;
}
```

But of course it handles only the case where array results from using brackets, for example:

```
["entry1", "entry2", settings.getMainUserEmail(), loginEmail]
```

Anyway the bottom line is that you need to return a `List` instead of array. Then you can also use `instanceof`.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I know if the result after eval() which is of type Object is an array?

Use `instanceof`:

```
if(result instanceof Object[]){
    //your code
}
```

> And if so, how can I cast it?

```
if(result instanceof Object[]){
    Object[] array = (Object[])result;
    for(Object o : array) {
    //your code
    }
}
```

Comment: That didn't work. The `instanceof` in the if statement returns false.

Answer (score 0):

```
final ScriptEngineManager scriptEngineManager = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine scriptEngine = scriptEngineManager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
scriptEngine.eval("count = ['one', 'two', 'three'];");
scriptEngine.eval("className = count.constructor.name;");

final String className =  (String) scriptEngine.get("className");

switch(className) {

case "Array":
    scriptEngine.eval("json= JSON.stringify(count);");
    final String json =  (String) scriptEngine.get("json");

    final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

    final String[] readValue = mapper.readValue(json, String[].class);
    break;

case "Number":
    ...
}
```